# India to UK visa for business refused due to wording issues

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, business-travel

I applied for a UK business visitor visa for two weeks and my application was refused having attached the following:

- My Bank statement
- Identity
- Passport
- Income tax returns.

Other than this, my company CEO provided the following documents, attached with application:

CEO's letter inviting me for a business visit in UK (they forgot to mention I'm an employee of this company, although they wrote they would providing accommodation and flight charges).

Other than this I attached copy of his passport and bank statement.

According to refusal notice they said "CEO had nowhere mentioned that you are their employee while you've said that in your application".

> "I am not sure you meet the requirement of Appendix V, Immigration
>   rules for visitors"
>
> you have sought the entry clearance to visit the UK for two weeks.
>   Your stated purpose is meeting and collaboration with with CEO, the
>   CEO of the company called COMPANY. CEO has provided a letter of
>   support for your application, which states that you have a work
>   related meeting with him. I note whereas you state you are employed by
>   “COMPANY”, CEO makes no mention of this in his letter, stating only he
>   is a CEO of a company called COMPANY. You have not provided any
>   evidence that you are employed by this company in India or else where.
>
> "Therefore I am not satisfied as to your motives to seeking entry in
>   UK at this time. I am not therefore satisfied that you intend to leave
>   united kingdom at the end of your visit. I'm also not satisfied that
>   you are genuinely seeking entry for a purpose permitted by visitor
>   routes and you will not undertake any of the prohibited activities
>   under V4.5 - V4.10. V4.2 (a) (c) and (d)"
>
> Future Applications -
>
> Any Future UK visa applications you make will be considered on their
>   individual merits, but they may be refused unless:
>
> - Your personal circumstances change significantly between now and your next application.
> - Your provide compelling new evidence with your application.

I'm not sure what to do now, I would need to apply again and pay visa fee again?

They have also written there is no right of appeal, nor of administrative review.

Comment: Can you provide the exact details of the refusal letter? Section you were refused under, reason given etc. That'll help us help you

Comment: @Gagravarr - Just added the notice text as it is, Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, in general you need to apply again, with your new application having corrected the insufficiencies of the previous application.

Comment: @user2119554   Nobody starts a refusal notice with "I am not sure"  And then the next paragraph starts with "therefore"?  Doesn't happen. There is not a lot that can be done if you include only the last two paragraphs of your refusal notice.  Somebody has already asked you to do that, but with what you have provided, you are most likely wasting your time here.   Close voting as unclear.

Comment: @GayotFow - I'm sorry but this is all I see over refusal letter I got.

Comment: @GayotFow - I'm not sure I should post the whole refusal letter somewhere, Is it ok to do - If yes what's would be the safest place ?

Comment: @user2119554, you can edit your question and post the text making any necessary redactions like names, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*They have also wrote there is not rights for appeal or administrative reviews.*

This is not a problem.  They write this paragraph in *all* refusal notices where the application is for a term of 6 months or less.  It is 'boilerplate'.  So the paths of appeal or administrative review are not options for you.  Even if an appeal *were* allowed, it costs GBP 140 to reach the hearing stage; this compares unfavourably to the cost of a fresh application, which is GBP 83.

*I'm not sure what to do now, I would need to apply again and pay visa fee again?*

Following a refusal of an application where the term is 6 months or less, everything starts at square 1.  It means you will have to complete the form again, collect and submit your evidence again, do your biometrics again, and pay the fee(s) again.

Also, since the ECO was citing from [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423477/20150424_mmigration_rules_app_v_final_v2.pdf), it means your application was *not* considered as a business visit, but rather as a [standard visitor](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).  You should adapt your application strategy accordingly.

History tells us that it is unwise to submit a fresh application without a detailed analysis of the refusal because it contains the 'legal' text. That's why people asked to see it in the comments above. You provided only a partial text (which is boilerplate and tells us nothing), and hence the best answer for the part of your question "*I'm not sure what to do now...*"  is to fix the deficiencies  and make a fresh application, consulting a [legal professional](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/) if necessary.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions - Just updated the question with further refusal notice details, Please suggest.

Comment: I see it. You failed on premise!  The CEO letter might help, but is not the solution.  Probably you should ask a new question; this question has been answered by two people.

Comment: How about sending a apologize letter by company, saying "they missed it and they are liable that I would be leaving UK with in given time."

Comment: @user2119554, when they stop laughing they will bin it.  Really... you need to ask questions like that in a different question.

Comment: @user2119554, I know it's frustrating.

Comment: "Also, since the ECO was citing from Appendix X, it means your application was not considered as a business visit, but rather as a standard visitor. You should adapt your application strategy accordingly" - I'm applying again not sure what you mean by this, would you please expand on same ?

Comment: @user2119554, oh my! It looks like a typo; I have fixed it to read 'Appendix V'. Nice call on your part.   Thankfully, the link is still correct!  This was from last June. At this point, your best option is to formulate a brand new question with your current situation so that it receives a very broad exposure to the site's visitors.  Like a summary of where things are right now and how you want to proceed.  People wanting to help may not be looking at June stuff, hence my suggestion.  Hope that is ok for you...

Comment: Thanks you so much @Gayot, Here's the new question - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52858/strategy-while-applying-for-visa-to-uk-2nd-time-after-first-refusal

Would be great if you can help on same.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you can appeal or not, the simplest thing is to reapply now. You have 'only' lost the fees of your original application and a little time, whereas any administrative review or appeal would take longer. Have your CEO write you a new letter, and reapply. Having said this, there may be another deficiency in your application which Visas & Immigration haven't noticed, but could refuse you for in the new application. If you need the visa urgently and cannot go through another round of reapplication then you might want to contact an experienced UK based immigration solicitor to make the application for you.

Comment: hey, thanks for your suggestions. Does that mean I would need to pay again for my new application and even if for some reason it gets refused pay again. that's creepy no ?

Comment: @user2119554 Yes, it is. But appealing to any sense of fairness will not work with UK Visas & Immigration.

Comment: Can you suggest with best way to get my application reviewed and avoid further refusals ?

Comment: @user2119554 Paying a UK based solicitor to handle your application is the safest option *but even this is not guaranteed*.