# UK visa refused. Can I now apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, visa-refusals

I applied for UK business visa 10 days ago and it was refused because of a missing document, Here is full question on same - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49744/30903

Now I need to go to Italy as a tourist, Can I apply ?

If yes, what else things I would need to take care of ?

Comment: Of course you can apply for a Schengen.  Right now if you want.  But 'what else things' is so vague that it would be difficult for anybody to nail it down.

Comment: @GayotFow - I meant to say, if I would need to put the reasons / clarification of the previous failed application ?

Comment: Schengen does not ask you to list previous UK refusals. They will know about it anyway. You have to look at the form and then get your question really focused so that lots of people can help with an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always apply. There is no specific delay between applications in the UK or Schengen area (even to the same country, let alone to different countries) and no automatic ban or anything like that following a mere refusal.

However, you may want to be careful to address the problem raised in the UK visa refusal because, even though some of the rules and guidelines are slightly different, Schengen consulates tend to have similar concerns.